# Basic queries in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

The following 2 variants of a query yield different results (The first one gives me the desired result). I don't know why. They appear same to me. Can someone help?

```
MATCH (gene:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov),
(actr:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov), (robin:Person{name:"Robin Williams"})
WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)
AND gene.name = "Gene Hackman"
RETURN  gene, mov, actr;

MATCH (gene:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov),
(actr:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov), (robin:Person)
WHERE gene.name = "Gene Hackman"
AND NOT (robin{name:"Robin Williams"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)
RETURN  gene, mov, actr;
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)
AND gene.name = "Gene Hackman"
```

Means "Where Robin did not act in a movie and where Gene's name is not 'Gene Hackman'"

This:

```
WHERE gene.name = "Gene Hackman"
AND NOT (robin{name:"Robin Williams"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)
```

Means "Where Gene's name is 'Gene Hackman' and where Robin Williams did not act in the movie."

See what's happening? The Gene Hackman filer is being made part of your `WHERE NOT` function. You'd need to either use your second example or rewrite the first like this:

```
MATCH (gene:Person { name: 'Gene Hackman' })-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov),
(actr:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov), (robin:Person{name:"Robin Williams"})
WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)
RETURN  gene, mov, actr;
```

I try to keep my `WHERE` syntax consistent across a query whenever possible. If I filter node or rel using the in-node syntax, I try to do the others the same way. It keeps things predictable and readable.

Comment: So does that mean WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)
AND gene.name = "Gene Hackman" is equivalent to WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)
AND NOT gene.name = "Gene Hackman" ....Notice the added NOT in the second condition

Comment: In terms of how we'd read and expect it to behave, yes. When you actually throw that into Cypher, the second `NOT` seems to remove the `WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mov)` entirely.